# NQueens - Recursive BackTracking Question

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I'm currently learning BackTracking algorithms with Python and the first question everyone typically starts with is NQueens. NQueens is where you take a board of size N x N and you have to determine where to place N queens, in such an order they are not attacked by any other queen.

Example:

N = 5

['Q', 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 'Q', 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 0, 'Q']

[0, 'Q', 0, 0, 0]

[0, 0, 0, 'Q', 0]

Currently, my algorithm returns ALL Possible Solutions. How do I produce ONE outcome. For instance, when N = 8, there are 92 optimal outcomes, how do I just return One Outcome instead of printing 92 separate Outcomes.

```
#This is our main recursive function that will determine optimal outcome
def NQueens(row,Current,N):
    #this tells us when to stop
    if row == N:
        print("\n")
        return printBoard(Current) 
    
    for choice in range(0,N):
        if isValid(row,choice,Current,N):
            #Place Queen in appropriate spot
            Current[row][choice] = "Q"
            
            #Go to next row
            NQueens(row+1,Current,N)
        Current[row][choice] = 0
    return "All Solutions Found"

#This function determines whether we can put a Queen in a certain orientation on the board
def isValid(row,col,Current,N):
    #check whether current state of game has queen in row/column
    for i in range(0,N):
        #checks column/row and sees whether a queen exists already
        if Current[row][i] == "Q" or Current[i][col] == "Q":
            return False
    
    # Check upper diagonal on right side 
    i = row-1
    j = col + 1
    
    #Do while row is greater than 0 and column is less than N
    while i >= 0 and j < N:
        if Current[i][j] == "Q":
            return False
        i -= 1
        j += 1
       
    # Check upper diagonal on left side
    #Do while row is greater than 0 and column is greater than N
    i = row-1
    j = col - 1
    while i >= 0 and j >= 0:
        if Current[i][j] == "Q":
            return False
        i -= 1
        j -= 1
    #If we pass the diagonal/row/column tests, we can then determine this is a valid move
    return True

###############################################################################################################
#These functions deal with board creation and printing them in a proper format
def generateBoard(N):
    #generate board based on User Input N in Main()
    Board = [[0 for i in range(0,N)] for j in range(0,N)]
    return Board

def printBoard(arr):
    #Loop through each row to print an organized board
    for row in arr:
        print(row)

def main():
    #ask number from user
    print("What sized board would you like?"
    " Please input a number higher that 3: ")

    #user input used to determine size of board
    N = int(input())

    #generate Board that will be used
    Board = generateBoard(N)

    #this is the current status of the board
    printBoard(Board)
    print("\n")

    #Runs Algorithm
    print(NQueens(0,Board,N))
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`NQueens` needs to communicate to its caller that a solution has been found; a simple `return True` will do if that's the case. I made the following changes to your code (your previous lines are commented):

```
def NQueens(row,Current,N):
    #this tells us when to stop
    if row == N:
        print("\n")
        #return printBoard(Current) 
        return True  # found a solution, say so

    for choice in range(0,N):
        if isValid(row,choice,Current,N):
            #Place Queen in appropriate spot
            Current[row][choice] = "Q"
        
            #Go to next row
            # NQueens(row+1,Current,N)
            if NQueens(row+1,Current,N):  # recursive call found a solution, let's stop
                return True
        Current[row][choice] = 0
    #return "All Solutions Found"
```

And in `main()`:

```
# ...
#Runs Algorithm
#print(NQueens(0,Board,N))
if NQueens(0,Board,N):
    printBoard(Board)  # found a solution, print it
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your code to have well-perfoming:
I merge this code https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-queen-problem-backtracking-3/ and yours to get it.

```
count = 1

def printOut(arrayMap):
    global count
    print('{}: -'.format(count))
    count += 1
    for i in range(0, len(arrayMap)):
        print(arrayMap[i])


# This is our main recursive function that will determine optimal outcome
def NQueens(currentRow, arrayMap, matrixSize):
    # this tells us when to stop
    if currentRow == matrixSize:
        print()
        printOut(arrayMap)
        return True  # found a solution, say so

    res = False
    for col in range(0, matrixSize):
        if isValid(currentRow, col, arrayMap, matrixSize):
            # Place Queen in appropriate spot
            arrayMap[currentRow][col] = 0

            # Go to next row
            # NQueens(row+1,Current,N)
            res = NQueens(currentRow + 1, arrayMap, matrixSize) or res # recursive call found a solution, let's stop

            arrayMap[currentRow][col] = 1
    # return "All Solutions Found"
    return res


# This function determines whether we can put a Queen in a certain orientation on the board
def isValid(row, col, arrayMap, matrixSize):
    # check whether current state of game has queen in row/column
    for i in range(0, matrixSize):
        # checks column/row and sees whether a queen exists already
        if arrayMap[row][i] == 0 or arrayMap[i][col] == 0:
            return False

    # Check upper diagonal on right side
    i = row - 1
    j = col + 1

    # Do while row is greater than 0 and column is less than N
    while i >= 0 and j < matrixSize:
        if arrayMap[i][j] == 0:
            return False
        i -= 1
        j += 1

    # Check upper diagonal on left side
    # Do while row is greater than 0 and column is greater than N
    i = row - 1
    j = col - 1
    while i >= 0 and j >= 0:
        if arrayMap[i][j] == 0:
            return False
        i -= 1
        j -= 1
    # If we pass the diagonal/row/column tests, we can then determine this is a valid move
    return True


###############################################################################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # ask number from user
    print("What sized board would you like?")
    N = int(input('Choose your size: '))

    # generate Board that will be used
    Board = [[1 for i in range(0, N)] for j in range(0, N)]
    count = 0
    NQueens(0, Board, N)
```